# Use WebRequest to check if a license is valid

Tags: c#, .net, security, webrequest

I am not a software engineer as you will see if you continue reading, however I managed to write a very valuable application that saves our company lots of money.  I am not paid to write software, I was not paid for writing this application, nor is my job title software engineer so I would like to have total control over who uses this application if I ever had to leave since as far as I can tell it is not legally theirs (did not write during company hours either).

This may sound childish but I've put much much time into this and I've been maintaining it almost on a daily basis so I feel that I should have some control over it, or at least could sell it to my company if they ever had to let me go, or I wanted to move on.

My current protection scheme on this application looks something like this:

```
string version;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://MyWebSiteURL/Licence text file that either says 'expired' or "not expired'");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
version = stream.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();
response.Close();

if (version == ("not expired") == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Environment.NewLine + "application expired etc etc", "Version Control");
}
```

It checks my server for "not expired" (in plain text), and if the webrequest comes back as anything but "not expired", it ultimately pops up another form stating it is expired and allows you to type in a passcode for the day which is a multiplication of some predetermined numbers times the current date to create "day passes" if ever needed (I think Alan Turing just rolled over in his grave).

Not the best security scheme, but I thought it was pretty clever having no experience in software security.  I have however heard of hex editing to get around security so I did a little test for science and found this area of my compiled EXE:

> "System.Net.WebRequest."  Which I filled in with zeros to look like this: System.Net000000000

That was all it took to offset the loading of the application to hiccup during the server check which allowed me to click "continue" and completely bypass all my "security" and go along using the program without it ever expiring.

Now would a normal person go to this length (hex editing) to try to get past my protection scheme?  Not likely, however just as a learning experience, what could I do as an added step to make hex editing or any other common workarounds not work unless it was by "professional" cracker?

Again I'm not  paranoid, I'm just eager to learn more about security of applications.  I was both proud of myself and ashamed at the same time for creating and breaking my own protection.

If commenting, please be kind since I know this is probably a humerus post to those more informed than I as I really have little experience in writing software and have never taken any type of course etc.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: It sounds like you should be talking to your company about getting compensation here, rather than resorting to technical measures.

Comment: @MitchWheat, he said he worked on it on his own hours.

Comment: That is a common hacking technique. Having one boolean check at the start of an application is easy to bypass. Have it check at multiple locations in your code, like every time a function is used, will make it more trouble to crack, but not impossible. bottom line, anything can be hacked. You can just make it more difficult for the average person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to bypass the license check is to redirect the checking url to localhost returning always the desired text...
A better way is to make a call to a function doing the same thing but make your server response a signed XML including the server response time-stamp, that you can check on addition with the system datetime (use UTC dates in both sides). It is also a good idea to throw exceptions whenever something is not the way you expect it, and control the flow of your program with exception handling.
Check the following to get a how to clue:
[How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx)
[How to: Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Now would a normal person go to this length (hex editing) to try to
>   get past my protection scheme?

Well i guess, that depends on how useful the application is for that "normal person", and how determines he is to make it work.

Most .net application unless obfuscated can be easily de-compiled to the source code using tools like ([Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)) or they can simple use the `ildasm` to see the IL code, i heard there are tools to even de-compile obfuscated .net libraries, although i haven't used or found any.

With my little experience, i can suggest two approaches

1. Enforcing licensing and cracking it in a application which runs plainly on the user machine is a [cat and mouse game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_and_mouse), you can add some extra protection to your code by moving some part of the applications functionality to the server and expose it as a web service which your client can consume, the part you move to the server must be an important part for the application to work and should be something that is hard to simulate.
2. The other approach is to add a auto updater feature to your application that will check the server for latest updates, and when ever it finds a new version it will overwrite the older one, thus overriding any cracked version, this can be easily disabled, but if disabled this will also stop any bug fixes you might release

I tried both the approaches, but they are only useful to some extent and you have to decide whether it is worth the effort enforcing or not

Comment: Yes I've decompiled before, very interesting!  Thanks for the info I liked all responses on this thread.